# Create a user-defined aggregate without SQL CLR

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, aggregate

I am planning on deploying a database to SQL Azure, so I cannot use the SQL CLR. However, I have a need to create an aggregate function -- in my case, I need to STUnion a bunch of Geography objects together. (Azure is expected to support Spatial by June.)

Is there another way to accomplish this, without making use of the CLR, in a query? Or do I have to create a UDF that will take a table as a parameter and return the aggregate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geography is supported in Azure SQL now.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it.